# Custom VBA UserForm Hotkey inside Form

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I want to have my userform close (or other commands) without using accelerator keys.

For example, the following form is opened from Excel when the user presses F4. I would also like it to close (Unload Me) with F4 too.

This is what I am using at the moment, although it seems unnecessarily large:

```
Private Sub TextBoxA_KeyDown(ByVal keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
moveme Val(keycode)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBoxB_KeyDown(ByVal keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
moveme Val(keycode)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBoxC_KeyDown(ByVal keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
moveme Val(keycode)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBoxD_KeyDown(ByVal keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
moveme Val(keycode)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBoxE_KeyDown(ByVal keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
moveme Val(keycode)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBoxF_KeyDown(ByVal keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
moveme Val(keycode)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBoxG_KeyDown(ByVal keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
moveme Val(keycode)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBoxH_KeyDown(ByVal keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
moveme Val(keycode)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBoxI_KeyDown(ByVal keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
moveme Val(keycode)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBoxJ_KeyDown(ByVal keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
moveme Val(keycode)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBoxK_KeyDown(ByVal keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
moveme Val(keycode)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBoxM_KeyDown(ByVal keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
moveme Val(keycode)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBoxN_KeyDown(ByVal keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
moveme Val(keycode)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBoxO_KeyDown(ByVal keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
moveme Val(keycode)
End Sub
Sub moveme(keycode As Integer)
If keycode = 115 Then Unload Me
End Sub
```

I guess I'm looking for something like this but I have no idea:

```
loop:
Private Sub TextBox[i]_KeyDown(ByVal keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Sub moveme(keycode As Integer)
If keycode = 115 Then Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Access you can put a function directly into the event code box of a control, including the same function for  multiple controls.

In Excel and Word, I think the only way to do this is to use WithEvents. Here's a couple of links to some info on the topic. If that's not enough, Google "Excel WithEvents". (WithEvents is one word.)

[Chip Pearson's site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx)

[Mr.Excel forum](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/65901-multiple-textboxes-same-code.html)

Comment: Thanks Pete, I have used elements of the second link to do just that. I have answered my own question with the code & marked your answer as correct as your answer would help others generally speaking.

Answer (score 2):

Each textbox needs its own event handler, for a number of reasons, also, while I understand what you *want* to do, you can't execute statements outside of procedures, so you can't like, create a series of `Private Sub TextBox[i]...` outside of a procedure.

Fortunately, there might be an easier way to do this using the `Application.OnKey`.

In a standard module, where you have a macro which initializes the form, do something like:

```
Sub showform()
    'Displays/initializes the form and assigns hotkey function to F4
    Application.OnKey "{F4}", "CloseForm"
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Sub CloseForm()
    'Sub to close the userform when F4 is pressed
    Unload UserForm1
    'optionally, revert F4 to its normal behavior
    'Application.OnKey "{F4}"

    'reset F4 to open the form:
    Application.OnKey "{F4}", "showform"
End Sub
```

If you are already using F4 to open the form, you'll need to tweak the logic a bit for example to check if the form is already displayed, or some error handling/etc.

**There are a few kinks to this though:** won't work while the form has focus, and therefore won't work unless form is displayed `vbModeless`. This doesn't work on a form displayed `vbModal` since, while a form is displayed that way, only form events would be recognized, so a hotkey would not trigger the close function *unless* it was called from a form object's event handler.

Otherwise, I think you are stuck handling each form object's events the way you have, or, possibly exploring the `WithEvents` option.

Comment: Thanks for the comment David, it was good to understand a bit more detail on the subject. I have answered my own question for the sake of the code but marked another user's answer as correct due to his leading to a broad range of options but your last point of WithEvents covered it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

David and Pete gave me some good insight for research so I have marked Pete's as correct - the Mr Excel forum link was extremely helpful. For the sake of the code, I ended up with the following but did not mark it as correct because perhaps it is too narrow for other users.

**Userform1 Code**

```
Dim TBs() As New TBClass

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim TBCount As Integer
    Dim Ctrl As Control
    TBCount = 0
    For Each Ctrl In Absence_Viewer.Controls
        If TypeName(Ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
            TBCount = TBCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve TBs(1 To TBCount)
            Set TBs(TBCount).TBGroup = Ctrl
        End If
    Next Ctrl
'Do other stuff
End Sub
```

**Class Module code named TBClass**

```
Public WithEvents TBGroup As MSForms.TextBox
Private Sub TBGroup_KeyDown(ByVal keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If keycode = 115 Then Unload Userform1
End Sub
```